# Why this piece of code returns 109?

Tags: c#, func, lambda

Could someone tell me how does it work? I would be grateful. Dunno how to debug this.

```
using System;

    class Prg
    {
        private static Func<double, Func<double, double>> Add(int c)
        {
            return x => y => x + y++ + (c *= 2);
        }

        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int a = 1;
            int b = 100;
            var F = Add(2);
            var G = F(a);
            G(b);
            Console.WriteLine(G(b));
        }
    }
```

EDIT: I have got another one if you want to enjoy our C# exam.. Here is the code.

```
delegate int F(); 
class Prg { int a = 10; 
  public F Adder(int x) { 
    int i = x; 
    return delegate { 
      return a += i++; }; 
  } 
  static void Main() { 
    Prg p = new Prg(); 
    F f = p.Adder(5); 
    p.Adder(10); 
    f(); 
    System.Console.Write(f()); 
}  }
```

Comment: What is this from? Some obscure code challenge?

Comment: Dykam made a point. "Never try this at home!" However if anyone wanted to point out the specific behavior of a memory variable allocated and referenced by lambda, a much better example could be made.

Comment: This is one of the tasks from C# exam I have.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I will start with: don't write such code, ever.

And if you really want to know what is happening:

1. in line `var F = Add(2)`, method Add() creates and returns a lambda expression with c==2. What is important here, is that `c` is caught by lambda (you can read about capturing variables on [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx).
2. In line `var G = F(x)` you are simply calling your function with parameter `a = 1` and you get another function as a result, `double -> double` to be exact.
3. In line `G(b)` you are calling your function, exactly this one: `x + y++ + (c *= 2);` Now:

   - x is equal to 1
   - y is your parameter, it is equal to 100
   - c is equal to 2, but it is captured, so it is actually a reference to some allocated field
   - Result of this expression is 105 (100++ returns 100, 2 *= 2 returns 4), so you get 1 + 100 + 4 = 105. But, what is more important, variable c, which is captures is now equal to 4. y was just a parameter, so it did not change.
4. In line `Console....` you are invoking your function again. This time, parameter is again equal to `100`, so a result would be identical, but your captured variable `c` is now equal to 4, so a result you receive `1 + (100+) + (4 *= 2) -> 1 + 100 + 8 -> 109`

Here's a short example that might shine some light on what has happened there:

```
class Prg
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int captured = 5;
        int param = 3;

        var func = new Func<int, int>(x => x * captured);

        Console.WriteLine(func(param));
        captured = 6;
        Console.WriteLine(func(param));

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This part executes twice:

```
c *= 2
```

The first time when you call G(b). The second time when you print to console.

One execution actually calculates:

```
a + b++ + (c *= 2)
```

But since c gets multiplied by 2 (and assigned back to c) on each execution, you get 109 instead of 105. **Variable `c` is referenced as one exact memory location in the scope of function Add, actually used as Func delegate** (and instance of Func remains the same all the time), that's why this is not the same as if you would do some nested calls with functions (where only the transfer by value would occur into the function, the value would be returned, the scope of function closed and never accessed again with the same context).